# \Zend\Stdlib & Laminas - \Zend\Stdlib\ParametersFactory - Failing Module

Tags: third-party-module, magento2.4.6, zend-framework, setup-di-compile, laminas

After (unwisely it seems) doing composer update on our Magento 2.4.6p1 (php 8.2), some recent updates seem to have caused problems with Zend and Laminas. Most of which were easily fixed by replacing the references with the updated Laminas reference.

However this module (cybersource/module-secure-acceptance) has several references to \Zend\Stdlib\ParametersFactory in the file which doesn't seem to be referenced anywhere. The module worked fine before however now it won't compile. I've tried replacing directly Zend with Laminas but this seems to break the module too.

I've spoken with their team but they're slower than slow can get and I'm sure it's some simple fix that we haven't found yet.

Here's the full file too if necessary. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

namespace CyberSource\SecureAcceptance\Controller\Adminhtml\Transparent;

use CyberSource\Core\Model\Logger;
use CyberSource\SecureAcceptance\Gateway\Request\AbstractRequest;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class Response extends \CyberSource\Core\Action\CsrfIgnoringAction
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface
     */
    private $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement
     */
    private $quoteManagement;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory
     */
    private $resultLayoutFactory;

    /**
     * @var \CyberSource\SecureAcceptance\Helper\RequestDataBuilder
     */
    private $requestDataBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $quoteRepository;

    /**
     * @var \CyberSource\SecureAcceptance\Gateway\Config\Config
     */
    private $config;

    /**
     * @var \CyberSource\SecureAcceptance\Gateway\Config\SaConfigProviderInterface
     */
    private $configProvider;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $orderRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    private $coreRegistry;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\Create
     */
    private $orderCreateModel;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\GiftMessage\Model\Save
     */
    private $giftmessageSaveModel;

    /**
     * @var \Zend\Stdlib\ParametersFactory
     */
    private $parametersFactory;
    
    /**
     * @var \CyberSource\Core\Model\Logger
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * Response constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $sessionManager
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement $quoteManagement
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory
     * @param \CyberSource\SecureAcceptance\Helper\RequestDataBuilder $requestDataBuilder
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
     * @param \CyberSource\SecureAcceptance\Gateway\Config\Config $config
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\Create $orderCreateModel
     * @param \Zend\Stdlib\ParametersFactory $parametersFactory
     * @param \Magento\GiftMessage\Model\Save $giftmessageSaveModel
     * @param \CyberSource\Core\Model\Logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $sessionManager,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement $quoteManagement,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory,
        \CyberSource\SecureAcceptance\Helper\RequestDataBuilder $requestDataBuilder,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository,
        \CyberSource\SecureAcceptance\Gateway\Config\Config $config,
        \CyberSource\SecureAcceptance\Gateway\Config\SaConfigProviderInterface $configProvider,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\Create $orderCreateModel,
        \Magento\GiftMessage\Model\Save $giftmessageSaveModel,
        \Zend\Stdlib\ParametersFactory $parametersFactory,
        Logger $logger
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);

        $this->checkoutSession = $sessionManager;
        $this->quoteManagement = $quoteManagement;
        $this->resultLayoutFactory = $resultLayoutFactory;
        $this->requestDataBuilder = $requestDataBuilder;
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
        $this->config = $config;
        $this->configProvider = $configProvider;
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->orderCreateModel = $orderCreateModel;
        $this->parametersFactory = $parametersFactory;
        $this->giftmessageSaveModel = $giftmessageSaveModel;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     *
     * Main action method.
     *
     * Processes SOP response and saves the order.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface|\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var array $transparentResponse */
        $transparentResponse = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $this->logger->debug(['response' => $transparentResponse]);

        $message = false;

        try {
            /**
             * Validate cybersource signature
             */
            if (!$this->isValidSignature($transparentResponse)) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('Payment could not be processed.'));
            }

            // rewriting CyberSource postback with magento order data to proceed natively
            $this->substitutePostWithOrderData();

            /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
            $quote = $this->orderCreateModel->getQuote();

            $quote->setCustomerId($this->orderCreateModel->getSession()->getCustomerId());

            $this->orderCreateModel->setPaymentMethod(\CyberSource\SecureAcceptance\Model\Ui\ConfigProvider::CODE);
            $this->orderCreateModel->setPaymentData(['method' => \CyberSource\SecureAcceptance\Model\Ui\ConfigProvider::CODE]);

            if ($giftmessages = $this->getRequest()->getPost('giftmessage')) {
                $this->giftmessageSaveModel->setGiftmessages($giftmessages)->saveAllInQuote();
            }

            $this->orderCreateModel->recollectCart();
            $this->orderCreateModel->saveQuote();

            $this->coreRegistry->register(AbstractRequest::TRANSPARENT_RESPONSE_KEY, $transparentResponse);

            $order = $this->orderCreateModel
                ->setIsValidate(true)
                ->importPostData($this->getRequest()->getPost('order'))
                ->createOrder();

            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Your order has been successfully created!');

            $successUrl = $this->_url->getUrl(
                'sales/order/view',
                ['order_id' => $order->getId(), '_secure' => $this->getRequest()->isSecure()]
            );

            if ($this->isResponseRedirect()) {
                return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setUrl($successUrl);
            }

            $message = $this->messageManager->getMessages()->getLastAddedMessage();
            $message->setIsSticky(true);

            $parameters['order_success'] = $successUrl;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $parameters['error'] = true;
            $parameters['error_msg'] = $e->getMessage();
        }

        if ($this->isResponseRedirect() && isset($parameters['error_msg'])) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($parameters['error_msg']);
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('sales/order_create/index');
        }

        $this->coreRegistry->register(\Magento\Payment\Block\Transparent\Iframe::REGISTRY_KEY, $parameters);

        $resultLayout = $this->resultLayoutFactory->create();
        $resultLayout->addDefaultHandle();
        $resultLayout->getLayout()->getUpdate()->load(['cybersource_iframe_payment_response']);

        if ($message && $message->getIsSticky()) {
            $resultLayout->getLayout()->getBlock('dummy'); // trigger layout build to clear messages except our one
            $message->setIsSticky(false);
        }

        return $resultLayout;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    private function isResponseRedirect()
    {
        return !$this->config->isSilent() && !$this->config->getUseIFrame();
    }

    /**
     * Validate response signature with secret key.
     *
     * @param $response
     * @return bool
     */
    private function isValidSignature($response)
    {
        $storeId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('req_' . \CyberSource\SecureAcceptance\Helper\RequestDataBuilder::KEY_STORE_ID);
        return $this->requestDataBuilder->validateSignature($response, $this->configProvider->getSecretKey($storeId));
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    private function substitutePostWithOrderData()
    {
        $orderData = $this->checkoutSession->getOrderDataPost();

        if(empty($orderData)){
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('Sorry, Order data not found. Please try again'));
        }
        /** @var \Zend\Stdlib\Parameters $postParams */
        $postParams = $this->parametersFactory->create();
        $postParams->fromString($orderData);

        $this->getRequest()->setPost($postParams);

        $this->checkoutSession->unsOrderDataPost();

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to require the package "laminas/laminas-zendframework-bridge" in composer yourself. For some reason it went missing in the newest M2 upgrade and causes some backward compatibility troubles.

> composer require laminas/laminas-zendframework-bridge

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes several modules failed after the last update. I knew something went missing but didn't know what. 

At least now I know!!! appreciate the help